# Instance attribute of an object from a class inherited from frame, how to check the type of the widget

Tags: python, tkinter, attributes

my code is :

```
from tkinter import *

class Inter(Frame):

    def __init__(self, fenetre, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, window, width=768, height=576, **kwargs)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH)
        self.compt= 0

        self.message = Label(self, text="No click")
        self.message.pack()

        self.button_quit = Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.quit)
        self.button_quit.pack(side="left")

        self.button_click = Button(self, text="Click", fg="red",
                command=self.click)
        self.button_click.pack(side="right")

    def click(self):

        self.compt += 1
        self.message["text"] = " number of clicks={}".format(self.compt)
```

I have created the object

```
top= Tk()
interface = Inter(top)

interface.mainloop()
interface.destroy()
```

I have tried `vars()` and `__dict__` methods, but I get the instance attributes(ie name of the widgets) of the object 'interface' as str. So I can't check if the widget is a button or a label, using .winfo_class( method.

Comment: `isinstance(interface, tk.Frame)` gives True

Comment: i don't uderstand what you try to do. Maybe add in question code which you try to use.

Comment: After creating the object interface, I want to go through all the instance attributes of that object and retrieve the value of instance attributes that are widgets of type 'Entry'. Because, I want to put this value in a variable which is used by another function. (In the complete code, I have many widgets, so I will be long to use "isinstance")

Comment: using `children` you can get only widgets and skip other atributes. But still you have to check every widget with `isinstance()` or `winfo_class()` - But you can do it in loop like in my answer.

Comment: I think you should add Entry to list when you created code

Comment: I do not understand your suggestion, can you give an example please, and what is the benefit to do this?

Comment: for me it is natural that when I create code and I know that I will need all values from Entry then I assign them to list - ie. `all_entry.append(tk.Entry(..))` and later I have all Entry in `all_entry`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. So, if I want the values of two Entry, instead of writing the 6 following instructions: self.enter_t0=Entry(self).place(x = 60, y = 20) ; self.enter_t0.pack() ; self.enter_t0.focus_set(); self.enter_a=Entry(self).place(x = 60, y = 40) ;  self.enter_a.pack() ; self.enter_a.focus_set(); I should use a list. But where can I write the instructions with methods .pack() and .focus_set(), when using a list to collect the values from Entry?

Comment: after appending to list this Entry is last on list - `all_entry[-1]` - so you can do `all_entry[-1].pack()` But I rather use local variable `entry = Entry(...)` and `entry.pack()`, etc. and then put it on list `all_entry.append(entry)`. Using list I don't need `isinstance/winfo_class` to seach all `Entry` in widget.  And I can put only some Entry on list which I send to other functions. I can also create many lists - if I would creat table with many Entry in many rows then I can keep Entry from different rows  in different lists.

Comment: in your example in last comment I see two mistakes. (1) `pack()` and `place()` (and `grid()`) are different layout managers and they are used to places widgets in different way. `place()` put widget in position (x,y) and doesn't move it. `pack()` doesn't define position (x,y) because it automatically arange widgets (one to another). If you use `place()` then don't use `pack()` (or `grid()`) and when you use `place()` then don't use `place()`

Comment: second mistake: this `entry = Entry().place()` or `entry = Entry().pack()` or `entry = Entry().grid()` assigns `None` to variable because `place/pack/grid` returns `None`. You have to do it in two lines `entry = Entry()` and then `entry.place()` or `entry.pack()` or `entry.grid()`.

Comment: Documentation: [place](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm), [pack](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm), [grid](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm), and [more](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply compare the object type, like you can with any other python object:

```
>>> isinstance(self.button_click, Tkinter.Button)
True
```

The method you are looking for is **winfo_children**.

> **winfo_children()**
>
> Returns a list containing widget instances for all children of this
>   widget. The windows are returned in stacking order from bottom to top.
>   If the order doesn’t matter, you can get the same information from the
>   children widget attribute (it’s a dictionary mapping Tk widget names
>   to widget instances, so widget.children.values() gives you a list of
>   instances).
>
> *syntax* : `root.winfo_children()`

Comment: But in the complete code, I have many instance attributes ( many widgets), and I do not want to write such a line for each of them. So I want to retrieve all the instance attributes in a list, and test the type of each of them, using a loop

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check classes for children in `interface`

```
for name in interface.children:

    widget = interface.nametowidget(name)

    print(name, 'is Button:', isinstance(widget, tkinter.Button))
    print(name, 'is Label:',  isinstance(widget, tkinter.Label))

    print(name, 'is Button:', widget.winfo_class() == "Button")
    print(name, 'is Label:',  widget.winfo_class() == "Label")
```